# After a process forks and we have a new cloned process, will closing a file in the child's table affect the table in the parent?

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, fork, file-descriptor

Given **Process A** with a file descriptor. Process A `forks()` and creates a clone of itself. Let's call it **Process B**. Now, each of the processes A and B have their own descriptor. However, changing a value in the child will not affect the value in the parent. So, say for example I call `close(3)` in the child, the child initially had the same values as the parent when it was created. But now if the parent still assumes that the file is open(since there is a detachment between what happens in the parent and child's descriptor tables), wouldn't this cause a conflict? Wouldn't the parent still assume that the file is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When file descriptors are inherited during a `fork`, closing the descriptor in the parent has no effect on the corresponding descriptor in the child, and vice versa.

Here's an example from the man page for `pipe` that does exactly this:

```
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <assert.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pfd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       assert(argc == 2);

       if (pipe(pfd) == -1) { perror("pipe"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pfd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pfd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pfd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pfd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pfd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pfd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);             /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. This I am aware of. But the question is, at the beginning of the fork(), both of the tables contain descriptors and the child has the same exact entries as the parent, what happens if I close a file in the child? How is it possible for the parents to still think it is open?

Comment: @Ralphyabro Closing the file in the child closes it only for the child.  The file is still open for the parent.  That's the way the OS implements it.

Comment: So I can think that if the child closes a file, the file is closed for the child for its scope of use. But the file could be in parallel used by some other process, so the parent process can continue using it normally. I think my confusion was that the state of the file changes, but now I understand that each process will have its own "instance" of the file

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will affect. Because, both the process A and Process B are points the same file table entry for that file descriptor. If the both process are points the same file table entry then the file offset and file status flag are shared.
If it is shared is there any one process close the file, it will affect the another process.